Creating a consistent formula format painter with Office.Js
I am trying to develop a consistent formula painter with office.js for purposes of reviewing financial models. The script is meant to be run on the active sheet and will color code it using the following logic:

If the cell is text, highlight grey.
If the cell is a formula....


Check to see if the formula to the left is the same formula (using R1C1 formulas), if so highlight it green.

If there is no formula to the left or if the formula to the left is different (again R1C1 formula), then highlight it yellow.


I have been able to get a JSON string of the formulas in R1C1. I am not sure how to proceed to the next step to loop through the JSON by row, evaluate using the logic above, and then finally apply the formula changes listed above.
$("#run").on("click", () => tryCatch(getFormulas));

async function getFormulas() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const range = sheet.getUsedRange();
      range.load("formulasR1C1");
      range.load("address");

      await context.sync();

      //const sheetFormulas = JSON.stringify(range.formulasR1C1, null, 4);
      const sheetFormulas = JSON.stringify(range.formulasR1C1, null, 4);
      const sheetFormulas2 = JSON.parse(sheetFormulas);

      console.log(sheetFormulas);
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    //handle error
  }
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}


Have you read Conditional formatting of ranges? Especially the section "Custom".

It is an interesting approach that I didn’t consider. I will look into it.
I originally built this as a VBA add-in and trying to rebuild in an office.js add-in.
